# CSS3 Background Repeat on One Side

Tags: html, css

I'm a bit new to CSS3 and I am trying to make a background repeat endlessly but only on one side of the screen, such as the polka dot background menu on the right hand side of  http://www.google.com/analytics/

Can someone tell me how this is created?

Comment: I hate when people downvote without an explanation but I can tell you why they probably downvoted. You can easily google this question. Look at documentation for background in CSS. Then after you have attempted and have some code to show we can help you with your problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
background-position: right;
background-image: url('');
background-repeat: repeat-y;
```

Answer (score 0):

The background is filling a content block, backgrounds don't have to only be applied to the body element.